# Error handling for Address not found in mule SMTP

Tags: mule, mulesoft

When sending the mail using SMTP to the user's email sometimes mail is not sent because user's email is not correct.

Because the error is not occurred in mule, I got a success response but in email (from which email is sent) it shows "Address not found".

How to handle and generate a error for this in mule.

Comment: Please add to your question exact Mule version and connector version and the exact and complete error message, copied from the text in the log. Use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.